# Transmission will not run shell script after torrent download completed

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, bittorrent

I am looking to have the Transmission bittorrent client execute a script that changes the owner and permissions of all torrents in the completed folder when a torrent completes downloading.

I am using the following relevant settings in /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json:

```
"download-dir": "/data/transmission/completed",
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/home/user/script.sh",
```

The script does not seem to be executing after a torrent completes, I know there are other issues that could be going on aside the from the content of the script itself. The owner of the script file is debian-transmission and I have the permissions set to 777, so there shouldn't be an issues with Transmission accessing the script unless I have missed something here.

The /home/user/script.sh file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo sudopassword | /usr/bin/sudo -S /bin/chmod -f -R 777 /data/transmission/completed
echo sudopassword | /usr/bin/sudo -S /bin/chown -f -R user /data/transmission/completed
```

I know it is poor form to use a sudo command in this fashion, but I can execute the script on it's own and it will work correctly. I am not sure why Transmission is not executing the script. Transmission supports some environment variables such as TR_TORRENT_NAME that I would like to use once the script is being triggered. Is there anything I am not setting up in the file that would prevent the script from working correctly and how would I use environment variables?

Comment: How about the permissions of your home folder. If it's `750` for instance, then it won't matter what permissions have been given to the script. As for the environment variables, you should be able to use those in your script.. something like `chmod 777 /data/transmission/completed/${TR_TORRENT_NAME}` for instance.

Comment: I moved the script into /etc/transmission-daemon and was able to confirm that the script is firing putting a simple touch command in script. However it does not seem to be working with the

    "/bin/echo sudopassword | /usr/bin/sudo -S /bin/chmod -f -R 777 /data/transmission/completed"

command. Would the script not be able to act upon the folder because of any other permission settings?

Comment: Ah! ok that's good troubleshooting. Using `sudo -s` are you including a newline character at the end of your echo'd password like: `echo "password\n" | sudo -s <command>` ?

Comment: I have not been doing that. Is it necessary to include a new line command when using the echo password workaround? I am relatively new to these commands and Linux itself. I'm learning things as I go setting up a Plex server on Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Yep. Oddly enough... it's necessary. If you run your command manually you'll find that it asks you for a password if you leave off the newline character. Adding the newline will allow the command to be ran by su unprompted.

Comment: `chmod 777` is a **horrible** idea; it lets even untrusted accounts modify a script your other account is executing; in effect, it completely defeats the system's security model -- the last thing you want to do on a machine that's downloading untrusted content from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

##### Add the *user* who will execute the script to a *group* with default *sudo* access.

---

##### ***Fedora*** - add user to the `wheel` group

#### `sudo usermod -aG wheel $(whoami)`

##### ***Ubuntu*** - user group: `sudo` or `admin` *(deprecated)*

Comment: transmission could also execute as user: transmission
`sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep transmission`

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably answer a different question here, but if you're trying this simply to gain write permissions on your Transmission Daemon's downloads to your user, try a different approach.

I'm running my Transmission Daemon under my username, as set in it's `systemd` service file. (`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service` in my case)

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser      # set user here
Group=mygroup    # set group here :) 
UMask=0022       # 0022 gives 644 permissions on files (u+w), 0002 gives 644 (g+w), 0000 gives 666 (a+w)
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s STOP $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Notice `User`, `Group` and `UMask` (with capital M) directives.
See [Execution environment configuration for Systemd manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).

Then run:

```
sudo chown -fR user /data/transmission/completed
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service transmission-daemon restart
```

and you should set :)